# Customizing the progress view in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have an RCP application on Eclipse that makes quite a lot of use of jobs. This causes the Progress View to become cluttered at times and difficult to easily read.

Is it possible to extend to progress view to filter or tab the running jobs by category? Or is this beyond its intended use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Progress View code is all internal and we don't have any plans to make it extendable. You should think about suggestions (1) and (2) by @aav The suggestion (3) can't be done, as IJobManager won't give you the actual progress.

Comment: My issue with (1) and (2) is that despite these jobs cluttering the progress view it is important that all of them can be seen individually.

Answer (score 3):

You can:

1. set group several jobs together - use *setProgressGroup* method on your job. Jobs, related to same progress group will be presented by single entry in the progress view.
2. mark job as system - use *setSystem(true)* method on your job instance. Jobs, that are marked as system, are not visible in the job view, by default.
3. implement your own view, that displays running jobs. You should use *IJobManager* to attach a listener, that will receive job status notifications.